# Symfony/Api Platform ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have some trouble configuring many to many relations.

Here is what I have done:

Here is my Commercial entity, which has to be the owner of the relation.

```php
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Employee::class, inversedBy="relations", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinTable()
* @Groups({"read_commercial"})
*/
private $relations;
```

And my Employee entity which old the relation to.

```php
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Commercial::class)
* @Groups({"write_employee", "read_employee", "read_commercial"})
*/
private $relations;
```

Whenever I try to put on my Commercial Entity as

```
{
   "relations": ["/api/employees/1"]
}
```

The attribute relation still appears empty.
I first thought about a mistake in the serialization groups but can't find it.

Comment: https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1628